# SWIFT(5.0 or Later) & Xcode(12.5) : Retrieving an Image from a tuple to serve as a button background

Tags: swift, image, button, background, tuples

My Goal:

Create an instance of an Image with associated Value to serve as a card in a card game.

Images are loaded like so into my ContentView.swift class:

```
let cardM1:Image = Image("Card_Minus_I")
let cardM2:Image = Image("Card_Minus_II")
let cardM3:Image = Image("Card_Minus_III")
let cardM4:Image = Image("Card_Minus_IV")
let cardM5:Image = Image("Card_Minus_V")
let cardM6:Image = Image("Card_Minus_VI")
```

The next step is to insert images and values into a tuple:

```
var tupleDeck = [-1:cardM1,-2:cardM2,-3:cardM3,-4:cardM4,-5:cardM5,-6:cardM6]
```

Now, I'd like to change the background of a Button:

```
/*
 PlayerHandButton struct is in charge of providing
 stylizing that could be applied to any button
 that represents a card in a player's hand.
 */
struct PlayerHandButton: ButtonStyle  {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            
            .background(Image("cardSpot"))
```

to

```
.background(tupleDeck.index(forKey: -1))
```

but, I get an error:

**Referencing instance method 'background(_:alignment:)' on 'Optional' requires that 'Dictionary<Int, Image>.Index' conform to 'View'**

```
    }   // End of makeBody func
}   // End of struct GameboardButton
```

Reading an article on Swift tuples and using a google search were fruitless endeavors.

Thank you for your time!

The picture shows the expected result of an image as a background of a button.

[image: Card spots populated and not.]

Comment: `index(forKey:)` returns the index, not the value: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641173-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to use names for tuple variables during the declaration:

```
var tupleCardP1 = (Value: 1, Image: cardP1)
```

The succsessfull call to change a background of a button:

```
        .background(tupleCardP1.Image)
```

Result:

[image: Plus One Card with the value of positive digit one]